# How to manipulate sas7bdat files?

Tags: sas

I'm working with a sas7dbat file that was created erroneously and trying to fix it. When the file was created, the data was all input unto a single column instead of multiples, and I can't figure out how to manipulate it to do this. I thought I'd be able to use infile and make the dlm "|" with dsd to remove the quotations on the name column, but it seems that this problem is harder than it looks.

I basically want to turn that one column into the six it was supposed to be and delete the quotations from the names. Here's what it looks like in SAS:

[SAS7dbat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL7EM.png)

And here's the datalines in case they're needed:

1   0017|2020-04-09|"Jason Nguyen"|122L|500.0|$404.82

2   0017|2020-04-09|"Jason Nguyen"|407XX|100.0|$201.95

3   0177|2020-04-05|"Glenda Johnson"|144L|100.0|$91.01

4   0177|2020-04-05|"Glenda Johnson"|188X|100.0|$70.76

5   0177|2020-04-05|"Glenda Johnson"|733|2.0|$101,230.00

6   0177|2020-04-05|"Glenda Johnson"|777|5.0|$106.29

7   1843|2020-04-03|"George Smith"|122|100.0|$60.64

8   1843|2020-04-03|"George Smith"|122L|10.0|$303.18

9   1843|2020-04-03|"George Smith"|144L|50.0|$91.01

10  1843|2020-04-03|"George Smith"|188S|3.0|$52,629.48

11  1843|2020-04-03|"George Smith"|855W|1.0|$92,210.41

12  1843|2020-04-03|"George Smith"|908X|1.0|$51,920.87

13  9888|2020-04-11|"Sharon Lu"|100W|1,000.0|$20.14

14  9888|2020-04-11|"Sharon Lu"|122|50.0|$60.64

(each line is one column inside SAS)

Comment: Go back and fix your import code.

Answer (score 0):

Go back and fix the import code would be my suggestion otherwise use the SCAN() function.

```
data want;
set have;


var1 = scan(variableName, 1, '|');
var2 = input(scan(variableName, 2, '|'), yymmdd.);
format var2 date9.;
var3 = dequote(scan(variableName, 3, '|'));

....

run;
```

Another option is to write the file as is back to a text file and then import it using the DLM='|' option.

Untested:

```
proc export data=have outfile='myfile.txt' dbms=dlm replace;
delimiter='';
run;

proc import out=want datafile='myfile.txt' dbms=dlm replace;
delimiter='|';
run;
```

Given that it's only 6 variables though you may as well write the data step for that code anyways.